# Trying to subtract an int by another int but I get an error

Tags: python

I am making a code to change Freiheit into Celsius. I don't understand why I get this error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'` even though my code makes everything an integer. Can anyone help me? Thank You in advance. The code is in python.

```
def FreiheitToCelsius():
    freiheit = input("Enter the number of Freiheit: ")
    freiheit = int(freiheit)
    firstResult = freiheit-32
    finalResult = firstResult*0.55555555555
    print(finalResult)
```

Comment: I guess that line should be `freiheit = int(freiheit)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using raw_input which usually isn't great for a lot of reasons.

You need to define what you want the input to be otherwise it will be considered a string:

So instead of `input("")`, you should use `int(input(""))`:

`freiheit = int(input("Enter the number of Freiheit: "))`

Here is a simpler example:

```
x = input("Using raw input: ")

print(x, type(x))
```

Would then output:

```
Using raw input: 52
52 <class 'str'>
```

In order to make 52 an int by default we need to define it:

```
y = int(input("Using int input: "))

print(y, type(y))
```

Which now gives:

```
Using int input: 52
52 <class 'int'>
```

Comment: Using `float(input (""))` gives a wider range of allowed inputs, however putting it in a try catch block would also catch not int (or float if you use float) inputs

Answer (score 0):

As you take in in the input, freiheit is a string.

In the second line, it seems that you made a typo and ended up substracting a string with an int.

```
def FreiheitToCelsius():
    freiheit = input("Enter the number of Freiheit: ")
    freiheit = int(freiheit)
    firstResult = freiheit-32
    finalResult = firstResult*0.55555555555
    print(finalResult)

FreiheitToCelsius()
```

An input of 40 gives me 4.4444444444.